# SwiftUI not updating state variable in ForEach loop function call

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I cannot seem to find a solution to this after much searching. I am trying to update my state variable `d` in the function call `addDay`. This function is called in the ForEach loop. The problem is, `d` is updated once to a value of 2.0, then it stays at 2.0 forever. I'm not sure what is wrong, any insight?

```
let weekdays: [String] = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri"]
    @State var startDate: Date = Date().next(.monday, direction: .backward)
    @State var d:Double  = 1.0
    
    /**
     - parameter startDate: the beginning date that will be modified
     - Returns: A new Text that has a date attached
     */
    func addDay(startDate: Date) -> Text {
        self.startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(86400 * self.d)
        self.d += 1.0
        return Text("\(startDate, formatter: Self.weekFormat)")
    }
    
    static let weekFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                ForEach(weekdays, id: \.self) { weekday in
                    VStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9, style: .continuous)
                            .stroke(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 68.5, height: 68.5)
                        
                        self.addDay(startDate: self.startDate)
                        Text(String(self.d))
                        Text(weekday)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you might be *modifying the view state during update*...

This is a fancy term for a possible never ending loop:

1. SwiftUI evaluates the view, which causes addDay to be called.
2. `addDay` causes `startDate` or `d` to change, both of which are `@State` variables.
3. SwiftUI sees that the view state to change, so it re-evaluates the view.
4. ( back to top :P )

Your case is a bit different however, because SwiftUI appears to be actually *stopping* the state change, which is probably good in your case because if it wasn't stopping the state change, your CPU usage would spike up to 100 percent.

---

#### But... how do I get around this?

For your particular situation I suggest handling it like so:

```
func addDay(_ index: Double) -> Text {
    let someDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(86400 * index)
    return Text("\(someDate, formatter: Self.weekFormat)")
}
```

**...**

```
ForEach(0..<weekdays.count) { weekday in
    VStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9, style: .continuous)
            .stroke(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 68.5, height: 68.5)
        
        self.addDay(Double(weekday))
        Text(String(Double(weekday)))
        Text(self.weekdays[weekday])
        
        
    }
}
```

This once again boils down to the way SwiftUI works, you can think of SwiftUI as a "function" of its states. In my example you can pass in *any* weekday, with it's position in the array, and you'll be able to generate a UI.

---

-Side note-

I did *not* know that you could access the static version of `self` by using `Self` (capital S). How convenient Swift is!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve, but here is a demo of approach of how to use temporary variables during view generation.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (original logic preserved)

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let weekdays: [String] = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri"]
    @State var startDate: Date = Date()//.next(.monday, direction: .backward)

    /**
     - parameter startDate: the beginning date that will be modified
     - Returns: A new Text that has a date attached
     */
    func addDay(startDate: inout Date, d: inout Double) -> Text {
        startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(86400 * d)
        d += 1.0
        return Text("\(startDate, formatter: Self.weekFormat)")
    }

    static let weekFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            genererateContent()
        }
    }

    private func genererateContent() -> some View {
        var d: Double = 1.0
        var startDate = self.startDate.addingTimeInterval(86400 * d)

        return HStack{
            ForEach(weekdays, id: \.self) { weekday in
                VStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9, style: .continuous)
                        .stroke(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 68.5, height: 68.5)

                    self.addDay(startDate: &startDate, d: &d)
                    Text(String(d))
                    Text(weekday)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```